# Matrix very slow when editing entries

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, control-panel

I currently have a matrix field within my channel entries. When this field is empty, the edit entries loads perfectly well. However, once data is added to the matrix field, for example i have an entry with 160 rows of matrix data, the edit entry page takes at least 60 seconds to load.

The server we are using is a fairly high spec dedicated server and we have increased php limits where possible to see if that helped.

The other problem is trying to save and edited entry when the matrix data is added. We have CSV imports running to import the matrix data regularly, but we will still need to make changes elsewhere within each entry after that. This is preventing us from doing so as it either takes 3/4 minutes to submit the edited entry or we get the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in ft.matrix.php on line 851

I appreciate with the amount of data we have it isn't going to be as quick as normal, but the amount of time it is taking at the moment is almost unusable.

Any assistance appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: What kinds of fields are you using in your Matrix columns?

Comment: They are all text input fields